# SNMP mib syntax error, unexpected MAX-ACCESS, expecting <

Tags: java, snmp, mib

I am using Mibble to parse MIBs but the errors have no description. To debug I run the mib through an online tool that checks the syntax. I have been able to correct some MIBs using this tool though I have come across a weird situation. The tool reports *"syntax error, unexpected MAX-ACCESS, expecting <"* I compared this file to another file and the syntax is the same and doesn't include any '<'. Below is the portion of the MIB that is causing the issue. What additional information do I need to troubleshoot? If it was SNMP v1 I know it would need to be ACCESS instead of MAX-ACCESS but it is used throughout.

```
ethernetPortTable        OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX     SEQUENCE OF ethernetPortEntry
    MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
    STATUS     current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Ethernet port table. This table contains one entry per physical Ethernet
         port."
    ::= { wipipeEthernet 1 }

ethernetPortTraps      OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { wipipeEthernet 2 }
```

**UPDATE**
The syntax error above is what I get using the online tool, not what mibble gives me.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've been to that github page before, even found a jar for mibble-parser etc which is nice but all of the documentation links back to the original mibble docs so it was a little confusing. I'll have to spend more time in that repo but have been able to parse mibs. I'm curious about the mib syntax error though do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: The code snippet you shared does not show any obvious error, so if you are testing in an online tool, that tool can be buggy enough to report such.

Comment: It should be "SYNTAX     SEQUENCE OF EthernetPortEntry" and EthernetPortEntry must be defined as a SEQUENCE.